# Powershell insert same attribute in multiples nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I need some help on this issue.

I need to insert a attribute on certain node of my xml file. My code allows me almost that, it insert de attribute, but not in all.In this example i have 3 childNodes, but i have samples with 2, 4 or even 5, and the result is the same.

Part of my xml:

```
  <WrittenResource>
    <ResourceLink>IVB1-20180808_01/IVB1-20180808_01_02ext.eaf</ResourceLink>  
  </WrittenResource>
  <WrittenResource>
    <ResourceLink>IVB1-20180808_01/IVB1-20180</ResourceLink>  
  </WrittenResource>
  <WrittenResource>
    <ResourceLink>IVB1-20180808_01</ResourceLink>  
  </WrittenResource>
```

My code:

```
   $xmlAtt1 = $xml.CreateAttribute("ArchiveHandle");
   $MediaColl=$xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.Resources.WrittenResource.ResourceLink
   Foreach($Media in $MediaColl) {$xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild.LastChild.LastChild.FirstChild.Attributes.Append($xmlAtt1)}
```

This is my result, all the time. I`m not be able to figure it out, what happen.

```
 <WrittenResource>
 <ResourceLink ArchiveHandle"">IVB1-20180808_01/IVB1-20180808_01_02ext.eaf</ResourceLink>  
 </WrittenResource>
 <WrittenResource>
 <ResourceLink>IVB1-20180808_01/IVB1-20180</ResourceLink>  
 </WrittenResource>
 <WrittenResource>
 <ResourceLink ArchiveHandle"">IVB1-20180808_01</ResourceLink>
```

Thanks again, for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
$targets = $xml.SelectNodes("//ResourceLink")
foreach($target in $targets) {
  $attrib = $target.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute("ArchiveHandle")      
  $target.Attributes.Append($attrib)
}
```

Output:

```
<WrittenResource>
    <ResourceLink ArchiveHandle="">IVB1-20180808_01/IVB1-20180808_01_02ext.eaf</ResourceLink>
  </WrittenResource>
  <WrittenResource>
    <ResourceLink ArchiveHandle="">IVB1-20180808_01/IVB1-20180</ResourceLink>
  </WrittenResource>
  <WrittenResource>
    <ResourceLink ArchiveHandle="">IVB1-20180808_01</ResourceLink>
  </WrittenResource>
```

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks a lot for your help, these lines working fine! Two questions: Why the need to use "OwnerDocument" property? Is imperative to use the Xpath Expression? Once again many thanks.

Comment: As to the "OwnerDocument" property - that's just the way PS work. More importantly - the reason to use xpath is that it's the most succinct and accurate method of zeroing in on a particular node or node element in xml; I tend to use it even in the simplest cases.